# copy one field to another field in access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have hit a roadblock in my access form and I've searched high and low for an answer.  I have a form (Enter Numbers) in which users enter information that obviously is stored in a table (Numbers).  I need to have a field (# of models) in the numbers table, however, I don't want to ask the users to input that information.  Furthermore, in another table (property info) I have that information already inputted.  Now before you tell me that it is redundant...blah blah blah, to store the same information in two tables.....the (# of models) field in the (property info) table may change, whereas by storing that number in the (numbers) table each time users enter info in the form, I'm getting a snapshot that will not change.

I have a textbox that uses a dlookup function to pull the (# of models) from the (property info) table and displays it in the form.  I had (and have no clue why it no longer functions properly) a button in the form, that when pushed would run the following code " text66 = models " Then I had a docmd.close so that it would put the dlookup result located in field (models) into (text66) whose control source is the field (# of models) in the (numbers) table.  This was functioning flawlessly, and then something happened, and now when I click the button I receive a "you can't assign a value to this object" error.

I don't care by what method I copy the dlookup result into the (numbers) table, but I would certainly appreciate any help in doing so!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Access 2010 and later you could use a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the [Numbers] table to grab a copy of the value from the other table:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

Comment: Gord......you are a lifesaver!!  I have been hitting my head on this for far too long, your macro worked beautifully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may work for you:

Use an update query. Add the second field, if you need to. Open the query designer. Drag the source field and destination fields onto the query designer. Open the sql view and make your code look like this:

UPDATE table name
SET field2 = field1;

Now execute the query.

field2 is the field you want data copied to. field1 is where the data resides.

There was a thread [here](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/761385-access-table-copy-data-one.html) regarding a similar question.

Comment: Trust me, I read that thread, so if I'm understanding you correctly, I then have a button that runs this query each time they want to save their results?  This isn't a one time update of fields, this needs to happen each time a user uses the form to enter data, and I only want the field in that specific record in the form/table to be updated, not all of the previous entries for that field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simpliest way (I think) :

```
CurrentDb.Execute "update TableName SET TargetField=SourceField", dbFailOnError
```